# What Star Trek episodes are set in the 20th century?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel

*Star Trek* has a *lot* of time travel in it and, more often than not, it seems that when they travel back in time, they go to the 20th century.  **Which *Trek* episodes are set in 20th Earth century?** I'll also include the movies, but not holodeck reconstructions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a bit of a list:

- 1930s & 1960s: DS9: 'Past Tense, Pt II
- 1930s: TOS 'The City on the Edge of Forever'
- 1944: ENT 'Storm Front Pt 1 & 2'
- 1944: ENT 'Zero Hour'
- 1947: DS9 'Little Green Men'
- 1950s: ENT 'Carbon Creek'
- 1953: DS9 'Far Beyond the Stars'
- 1968: TOS 'Assignment: Earth'
- 1969: TOS 'Tomorrow is Yesterday'
- 1986: *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home'
- 1990s: VOY '11:59'
- 1996: VOY 'Future's End Pt 1 & 2'

[Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/20th_century)

Comment: Now do the 19th century!

Comment: So this does not include Holodeck reconstructions?

Comment: there was one more episode from TOS where they go back to the roarin 20's called 'A Piece of the Action' Season 2 episode 17

Comment: @Fingolfin That was on another planet though 

Comment: @AndrewThompson Good question - no it doesn't

Comment: Thanks for helping to build Star Trek knowledge on SFF:SE.  +1 on both Q and A.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis My pleasure :D

Comment: Does [Far Beyond the Stars](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Far_Beyond_the_Stars_(episode)) count?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes it would - this actually deserves to be an answer in itself: great find that I'd quite forgotten about!

Comment: Oh, feel free to add it to your answer--better to have one complete list IMO!

Comment: @Hypnosifl I wouldn't want to deny you of any reputation - post it and receive the up votes you would rightly deserve!

Comment: I appreciate it, but honestly, it's no big deal--at this point I've been here so long I got more rep than I know what to do with ;)

Comment: @Hypnosifl Well, if you insist!

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I have some ideas about what you could do with that rep....

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Tell that to [this guy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/richard)!